# Enable access datasource across cross domain in IE through asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, internet-explorer, cross-domain

I am calling a web service using ajax from asp.net application, but unable to retrieve data from the service.

But when i enable the cross domain on IE

> Internet options ->  Trusted sites -> Custom Level -> Miscellaneous -> Access data sources across domains -> Enable

it works fine.

But how to enable it from the application, as we cannot expect every user to make IE setting changes.
Or, is there any other approach?

Comment: Any updates? I'm facing the same problem, in js ajax to remote server via IE9...

Comment: I found this link, [CORS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/669152/ASP-NET-Web-API-CORS-Authentication-SSL-and-self-s) hope this helps you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227740/how-to-programmatically-enable-data-sources-across-domains-in-browser

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this and there can be a number of variable. Here is a blog that talks about them and provides links on a number of solutions. [Web API, JSON, AJAX, CORS, Chrome 500 error and Authentication](http://toadcode.blogspot.com/2013/10/web-api-json-ajax-cors-chrome-500-error.html) Basically it is a CORS issue and on top of it, it could be the need to pass authorization headers if your services are protected.