# how to programmatically enable data sources across domains in browser.?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, browser

I am using `$.ajax()` function in my script which is calling web service from other domain. but I am getting error in IE. Then after doing research, I came to know error was coming due to Internet Explorer by default set `"Access data sources across domains" to "prompt"`. How to set it `"Enable"` using script..?

Code:

```
var serviceURL = "https://www.other-domain.com/webservice/showbills?billID=12458";

if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      var data = xhr.responseText;                                  
          var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data); // then parse into xml
          var xml = $(xmlDoc); // create doc
          console.log(xml);
          // show bill here in table.
       }
    }
 xhr.open('POST', serviceURL, true);
 xhr.send();

} else {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceURL,
        dataType: "text",
        crossOrigin: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
           var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data); // then parse into xml
           var xml = $(xmlDoc);// create doc
           console.log(xml);
        // show bill here in table.
        }
   });
}
```

This giving error in browser.

I am getting `SEC7120: Origin http://localhost:8080 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header`  and `SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied`

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has created its own solution for cross domain AJAX requests in Internet Explorer, called XDomainRequest.

There is a plugin for jQuery to support this: https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

You just have to include this script after including jQuery and then it should work.

Comment: This is for IE8 and IE9 only. They have mentioned on there website. Any other way I am just parsing XML received from other domain.

Comment: Yes, I know, but you didn't mention which IE version you use. IE10 and up actually shouldn't need that workaround. Which IE version are you testing with?

Comment: Our website should work in all IE browser. Currently I am using IE 10. I have updated question.

Comment: In your sample code you test if the browser is IE and if it supports XDomainRequest but still use XMLHttpRequest instead of XDomainRequest. Why is that?
I'd just remove the whole upper part and only use the block from inside your else statement. If you implement the jQuery plugin I mentioned, jQuery will automatically do all that work for you and use XDomainRequest when needed and XMLHttpRequest when not.
(Btw. do you use something like <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/> in your page's head section or maybe have set your IE to emulate an older IE version?)

Comment: Hello @igorshmigor its still not working...using above plug in also...I am getting `SEC7120: Origin http://localhost:8080 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header`  and `SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied`

Comment: But when In IE it go to internet option -> security -> custom level and set enable Access data access across domains then it works...

Comment: Oh, I see. Try the following: In the server response-header add: 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Comment: can't it be done on client side...? or any other solution..because I am using web service from other department on development server...I dont have access to server code i.e Servlet...

Comment: Since it's not possible to override the client's security settings with JavaScript, this is the only thing I could think of. Sorry :(. A different solution would be to create a web service on your own server which calls the web service from the other server and returns the result. Like let's say your site runs on mydomain.com, instead of calling the service via https://www.other-domain.com/webservice/showbills?billID=12458 you call it via mydomain.com/webservice/showbills?billID=12458 and that calls the service from other-domain.com and returns the result.